# yii2 fullcalendar month background color

Tags: css, yii2, fullcalendar

I have the following yii2fullcalendar from philippfrenzel:

```
<?=
yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget([
    'clientOptions' => [
        'height' => 'auto',
        'defaultView' => 'basic',
        'visibleRange' => [
            'start' => '2017-06',
            'end' => '2017-10',
        ],
    ],
    'ajaxEvents' => Url::to(['/makl/jsoncalendar'])
]);
?>
```

It's quite good, the only thing what disturbs me a little bit that every cell is white and you can't really know where a new month is starting. Can we change the background color of weekend days and months? E.g. first month can be white, but where a new month begins it could be a different color, 3rd month white again, 4th month colored again etc. Until now I haven't really found any relevant solution for that, and I'm afraid that it maybe doesn't even exist. Or maybe with creating a one month event...? I've tried this way, but unfortunately it's not working:

```
$this->registerJs("
var newEvent = new Object();
newEvent.start = '2017-07-01 00:00:00';
newEvent.end = '2017-07-31 23:59:59';
newEvent.allDay = true;
newEvent.rendering = 'background';
newEvent.backgroundColor = 'red';

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newEvent, true);
");
```

and this way also in controller:

```
$EventBgColorJuly = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
$EventBgColorJuly->id = $time->id;
$EventBgColorJuly->title = $time->profile_name;
$EventBgColorJuly->start = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('2017-07-01 00:00:00'));
$EventBgColorJuly->end = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('2017-07-31 23:59:59'));
$EventBgColorJuly->allDay = true;
$EventBgColorJuly->rendering = 'background';
$EventBgColorJuly->backgroundColor = 'red';
$events[] = $EventBgColorJuly;
```

But then my events are gone.
Can you please point me to the right direction? Many thanks!

Comment: screenshot please and working code if possibvle???